MySQL to show difference in values in 2 similar tables
I have table as follows (let's call it old data).



UNIQUE_PJT
PROJECT
JOB_TITLE
SALARY_A
SALARY_B




IT_9810_PR
IT_9810
Programmer
10000
6000


IT_9810_AC
IT_9810
Accountant
9000
4500


IT_9810_SPR
IT_9810
Programmer Sr
15000
8000


IT_9810_SR
IT_9810
Sales Representative
12000
9000




This data extends to thousand of rows with each Project having upto 100 rows.
UNIQUE_PJT is unique and can be used to compare data in the 2 tables.

Now I have newer salary data values in ditto same structure. Newer data facts:

Some Project have been added, some have been removed
Some Job Title have been added, some have been removed

new data table:



UNIQUE_PJT
PROJECT
JOB_TITLE
SALARY_A
SALARY_B




IT_9810_AC
IT_9810
Accountant
5000
8500


IT_9810_SPR
IT_9810
Programmer Sr
25000
12000


IT_9810_SR
IT_9810
Sales Representative
20000
15000



I want to show the changes in new data based on old data. Display pages are project and salary class specific. So, desired output is for Project IT_9810 and salary class SALARY_A:-



PROJECT
JOB_TITLE
SALARY_A




IT_9810
Programmer
10000 (·)


IT_9810
Accountant
5000 (-4000)


IT_9810
Programmer Sr
25000 (+10000)


IT_9810
Sales Representative
20000 (+8000)



What should be the best approach for this.
I tried keeping the old data as table_old and newer data as table_new. Now on project display page, I selected all values corresponding to a Project from table_new and for each result row of -UNIQUE_PJT, queried table_old. But this is very slow since it queries DB again and again.

In your table is it a column which uniquely identifies each row ? If not I do not think it is possible

'This data has similar Salary_X coloumns based on some biz logic' - is this relevant to the question , if yes what do you mean.. also how do you distinguish the 2 programmers? Personally, and voting to close because it's a matter of opinion I would keep everything in the same table with timestamps.

Yes Ergest, id is avaialble. A unique coloumn can be added as well, as per need.

Yes Salmon, just wanted to add that since there are multiple coloumns, I'm not picking the approach of adding Salary_A_old, Salary_B_old coloumns to the base table.

@AlexKey please edit the question and add show create table your_table_name for both of your tables.  I guess that id is used for the relationship in this case ?

What does salaray_a , salary_b mean for a job title?

I actually don't know that. But for a salary class X and project X, I need to show the change in values.

@ErgestBasha Updated with Unique_PJT coloumn.

There is no apparent reason why joining these 2 simple tables should be slow ,perhaps you haven't told us everything relevant, please add table definitions as text and your code attempt. And what is a project display page - there is no such thing in mysql

Provide sample data according to Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3. The data must include ALL change types.

@Salmon I am a fool. I was first querying table_new. Then for each row, running query separately to fetch data from table_old.
I should have used a simple JOIN all this time.

You should use a single query that joins the old and new data tables based on the UNIQUE_PJT field.
SELECT 
    new.PROJECT, 
    new.JOB_TITLE, 
    new.SALARY_A,
    CONCAT(new.SALARY_A, 
           CASE 
               WHEN old.SALARY_A IS NULL THEN ' (·)' 
               ELSE CONCAT(' (', 
                           CASE 
                               WHEN new.SALARY_A - old.SALARY_A > 0 THEN '+'
                               WHEN new.SALARY_A - old.SALARY_A < 0 THEN ''
                               ELSE ''
                           END,
                           new.SALARY_A - old.SALARY_A, ')') 
           END) AS SALARY_A_CHANGE
FROM table_new AS new 
LEFT JOIN table_old AS old ON new.UNIQUE_PJT = old.UNIQUE_PJT;


SELECT unique_pjt,
       old_data.project                      AS old_project,
       new_data.project                      AS new_project,
       old_data.job_title                    AS old_title,
       new_data.job_title                    AS new_title,
       old_data.salary_a                     AS old_salaryA,
       new_data.salary_a                     AS new_salaryA,
       COALESCE(new_data.salary_a) 
               - COALESCE(old_data.salary_a) AS change_salaryA,
       old_data.salary_b                     AS old_salaryB,
       new_data.salary_b                     AS new_salaryB,
       COALESCE(new_data.salary_b) 
               - COALESCE(old_data.salary_b) AS change_salaryB

-- this subquery collects all the unique index values,
-- regardless of whether they have been added or deleted
FROM ( SELECT unique_pjt FROM old_data  
       UNION DISTINCT                   
       SELECT unique_pjt FROM new_data   
       ) all_pjt

-- then join the data to this complete list
LEFT JOIN old_data USING (unique_pjt)
LEFT JOIN new_data USING (unique_pjt)

This query produces complete comparing. You may remove some columns if you do not need in them. Also you may add WHERE which compares old and new values and and removes those rows which have no difference in the data.

First find the job_title and respective projects.
select project, job_title from old_data 
  union
select project, job_title from new_data

Next find the Salary_A information from both tables and find difference between them.
So, your MySQL query should be:
WITH distinct_jobs as (
     select project, job_title from old_data 
     union
     select project, job_title from new_data
),
base_table as (
     select dj.project, 
     dj.job_title,
     d1.salary_a AS OLD_salary_a,
     d2.salary_a AS NEW_salary_a,
     CASE
          WHEN(d2.salary_a IS NULL) THEN NULL
          ELSE (d2.salary_a - d1.salary_a)
     END AS salary_diff
     from distinct_jobs dj
     LEFT JOIN old_data d1
     on dj.project = d1.project 
     and dj.job_title = d1.job_title
     LEFT JOIN new_data d2
     on dj.project = d2.project 
     and dj.job_title = d2.job_title
)
select project, job_title, 
  CONCAT(COALESCE(NEW_salary_a, OLD_salary_a), ' (',
     CASE 
       WHEN(salary_diff IS NULL) THEN '.'
       ELSE 
         CONCAT(CASE WHEN(salary_diff > 0) THEN '+' ELSE '' END, salary_diff)
     END, ')') as salary_a
from base_table

Output: 

Sample Code: db<>fiddle
Here I used a extra view table to understand easily. You may avoid that.
Thank You
